# creating fields for loading xml to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

im trying to upload a xml data feed to mysql so i can use the database with my php program. The problem that im having is usually i create the fields and import the feed. But the feed i have now is a bit strange..

```
<name>test</name>
<address>test address</address>
<phone>251447</phone>
</phone_count>
<pets>cat</pets>
</pet_count>
<images>
  <image>1.jpg</image>
  <image>2.jpg</image>
  <image>4.jpg</image>
  <image>16.jpg</image>
</images>
```

can someone tell me how can i create the fields for `</phone_count> </pet_count>` because those fields have only the closing tag.

how do i create a field for each image? because i haven't inserted data in a sub set.

im trying to load the data using

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/xml/data.xml'
INTO TABLE person_data
```

Comment: In XML, only </phone_count> or </pet_count> can not be a valid xml tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input XML file is broken, there is no such thing as a closing tag without a corresponding opening tag. The author of this XML flow probably meant `<phone_count/>` and `<pet_count/>` (notice the position of the forward-slash). This syntax is identical to (e.g.) `<pet_count></pet_count>`.

Regaring the method for importing this flow, you will not be able to do it with `LOAD DATA INFILE` because there is a 1-n (one-to-many) relationship between your main entity (I'm guessing something like "Contact") and Images. Ideally, there will be two tables in your database, such as `contact` and `image`, and `LOAD DATA INFILE` allows importing into one table at a time.

You would be better off parsing this file programatically in PHP.

*On second thought, if there are at most four images for one givent contact, then I could imagine a `contact` table with four `image1`, ..., `image4` fields, but I would not consider it good practice.*

Comment: Thanks... The problem was with data feed. They hadn't included the correct tags.